# Gmail refresh tokens, xoauth2 and general informations

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, nodemailer

I started using nodejs and nodemailer a week ago and I've got some questions about Gmail oauth.

I've set my client ID my secret ID pretty easily but now I'm stuck on a "problem", I'm using gmail refresh tokens for authorizing my botmailer to send newsletter emails, being said it seems that when the token expires my bot is no more authorized and I cannot send emails anymore.

Is there a way I can automatically update the refresh token in my code ?

This is what I got so far, thanks in advance!

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        xoauth2: xoauth2.createXOAuth2Generator({
            user: 'mybotemail',
            clientId: 'myclientid',
            clientSecret: 'mysecretid',
            refreshToken: 'myrefreshtoken',
            accessToken: 'myaccesstoken'
        })
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: "myemailverifiedabove",
  to: user,
  subject: "Hello world",
  generateTextFromHTML: true,
  html: "<b>Hello world</b>"
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(response);
  }
  transporter.close();
});
```

EDIT: Gmail also suspended my account once without even saying why, if some of you does know why, I would appreciate it.